# Null pointer error when tracing Cassandra query using java driver

Tags: java, cassandra

I'm trying to measure the server side query execution time for a query in Cassandra using the java driver. I'm using `rSet.getExecutionInfo().getQueryTrace().getDurationMicros()` where rSet is the result set for the query I'm executing. I manually turned on tracing using cqlsh and was able to get the trace through cqlsh but I get a null value when I try it with the java driver. Is there something else I should be doing to enable tracing while using the java driver?

**EDIT**

Adding code used to query and connect to the cluster.

The code snippet I use to query and measure server side execution time

```
ResultSet rSet = session.execute("SELECT * from quelea.users where user_id = " + userId +" ALLOW Filtering");
System.out.println("Server-side query Execution time : " + rSet.getExecutionInfo().getQueryTrace()).getDurationMicros());
```

The code I use to connect to the Cassandra cluster

```
public void connect(final String node, final int port)  
   {  
      this.cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).withPort(port).build();  
      final Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();  
      out.printf("Connected to cluster: %s\n", metadata.getClusterName());  
      for (final Host host : metadata.getAllHosts())  
      {  
         out.printf("Datacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s\n",  
            host.getDatacenter(), host.getAddress(), host.getRack());  
      }  
      session = cluster.connect();  
   }
```

Comment: We are going to need a litle more than that, like part of your code to determine the issue. As this stands all i can tell you is that somewhere there is a null value which is not teribly helpful...

Comment: Edited the question with the code.

Comment: Thanks, which line of the code above does the stacktrace point to because i can't really see anything obvious :(

Comment: The second line, the value returned by rSet.getExecutionInfo().getQueryTrace()).getDurationMicros() is null. So I'm getting a null pointer error when I'm trying to print out the value.

Comment: Although i haven't really had any experience in with casandra, reading the docs: `getQueryTrace() returns the QueryTrace object for this query if tracing was enable for this query, or null otherwise.` could this be the reason you get a NPE?

Comment: I did enable tracing via cqlsh, my question is specifically if I need to do anything extra for the java driver.

Comment: Oh i see, unfortunately i can't provide a good answer if that is the case. Apologies :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your provided code:

```
ResultSet rSet = session.execute("SELECT * from quelea.users where user_id = " + userId +" ALLOW Filtering");
```

It appears that you are not enabling tracing, which is why `getQueryTrace()` returns null, thus why `getDurationMicros()` throws a `NullPointerException`.   (**Note**:  when using `TRACING on;` in cqlsh, it only applies to your cqlsh session, not globally).

To enable tracing you can use [`enableTracing()`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.1/com/datastax/driver/core/Statement.html#enableTracing--), i.e.:

```
Statement statement = new SimpleStatement("SELECT * from quelea.users where user_id = " + userId +" ALLOW Filtering").enableTracing();
ResultSet rSet = session.execute(statement);
```

Comment: I thought that was the problem too and comented to the post but the op asured me that they have enabled tracing

Comment: I think Kapil interpreted enabling tracing in cqlsh (TRACING on;) as enabling tracing globally, but it does not, only for the cqlsh session (updated my answer to reflect that).  Alternatively, you can enable tracing globally with 'nodetool settraceprobability 1.0' but that is discouraged as it enables tracing for every query.